# Move Settings folder to settings.py

Tags: python, django, pycharm, settings

Recently I received a started project with Django and Python, the project is constantly giving us errors, but some of them are probably because the last programmer made a directory of settings instead a settings.py. My question is if there is some way of move all this .py in the settings folder to a new python file called settings.py, to optimize it.

I algo post the error message,

Thanks!

```
    PS C:\Users\jmtorices\Documents\shpssl-main> py manage.py runserver
Invalid line: ÿþSECRET_KEY=my_secret_key_value
Invalid line: 
Invalid line: DEBUG=True
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line: import environ
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line: env = environ.Env()
Invalid line:
Invalid line: environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'somepath/.env')) # < --where ever your.env lies inside project directory
Invalid line:
Invalid line: SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('somekeyInsidenvFile', env('somekeyInsidenvFile')) #
Invalid line: ÿþSECRET_KEY=my_secret_key_value
Invalid line: 
Invalid line: DEBUG=True
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line: import environ
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line: env = environ.Env()
Invalid line:
Invalid line: environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'somepath/.env')) # < --where ever your.env lies inside project directory
Invalid line:
Invalid line: SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('somekeyInsidenvFile', env('somekeyInsidenvFile')) #
Invalid line: ÿþSECRET_KEY=my_secret_key_value
Invalid line:
Invalid line: DEBUG=True
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line: import environ
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line:
Invalid line: env = environ.Env()
Invalid line:
Invalid line: environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'somepath/.env')) # < --where ever your.env lies inside project directory
Invalid line:
Invalid line: SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('somekeyInsidenvFile', env('somekeyInsidenvFile')) #
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 403, in get_value
    value = self.ENVIRON[var_name]
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\os.py", line 680, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'SECRET_KEY'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\Documents\shpssl-main\manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\Documents\shpssl-main\manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 425, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 419, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 373, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 66, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 417, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 73, in handle
    if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 84, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 71, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 179, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\Documents\shpssl-main\shpssl\settings\production.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\Documents\shpssl-main\shpssl\settings\base.py", line 39, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 197, in __call__
    return self.get_value(
  File "C:\Users\jmtorices\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\environ\environ.py", line 407, in get_value
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg) from exc
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Set the SECRET_KEY environment variable
```

Comment: Inside the settings folder you can have settings based on environments such as `local.py` `testing.py` `production.py` etc, then you can use a particular settings file based on your environment.

Comment: Post error please. use a directory for settings is totally normal and widely used in the field